# django reverse with namespace

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm getting this error:

```
The included urlconf 'unsitiodigital.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it.
```

The traceback points to this line

```
class Contacto(FormView):
    template_name = "contacto.html"
    form_class = FormContacto
    success_url = reverse("main:mensaje_enviado") -->This Line

    def form_valid(self, form):

        form.send_email()
        return super(Contacto, self).form_valid(form)
```

There are valid patterns, it works without the `reverse` line.
urls.py - general

```
urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^', include('main.urls', namespace="main")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

urls.py - main

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from main import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.Inicio.as_view(), name='inicio'),
        url(r'^quienes_somos/$', views.QuienesSomos.as_view(), name='quienes_somos'),
        url(r'^opciones/$', views.Opciones.as_view(), name='opciones'),
        url(r'^contacto/$', views.Contacto.as_view(), name='contacto'),
->      url(r'^mensaje_enviado/$', views.MensajeEnviado.as_view(), name='mensaje_enviado')
]
```

So, ¿which is the correct user of reverse?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The include path must be wrong

```
url(r'^', include('main.urls', namespace="main")),  # the 'main.urls' path must be wrong
```

There are some ways you can include other urls. Try to import the patterns from the main.url module instead

```
from main.urls import urlpatterns as main_urls

url(r'^', include(main_urls, namespace="main"),
```

You also have to use [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) in the success_url.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class Contacto(FormView):
    template_name = "contacto.html"
    form_class = FormContacto
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main:mensaje_enviado")
```

> It is useful for when you need to use a URL reversal before your project’s URLConf is loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked with reverse_lazy. The include was working fine. I'll look into reverse_lazy docs now to understand it.